# My First Scala Connection reset at socket.

Tags: scala

I am running this code on my docker centos:6 container. 
I am getting socket connection reset error

```
[root@f3379978de12 /]#
[root@f3379978de12 /]# cat ScalaTutorial.scala
object ScalaTutorial {
      def main(args: Array[String]){
            var i=0
    while ( i<= 10 ) {
            println (i)
            i +=1
    }
}
   }
   [root@f3379978de12 /]# scala ScalaTutorial.scala
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at scala.tools.nsc.HasCompileSocket.loop$1(CompileSocket.scala:34)
```

Comment: try it with `scala -nc` (aka `scala -nocompdaemon`). this will be the default in Scala 2.13